# inotifywait ignore while loop

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, inotify

I am having trouble with using `inotifywait` properly.

My environment is CentOS 8 Stream with i7-9700

`test.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -e modify ./test.txt |
while read dirname eventlist filename
do
  echo "Event catch!"
done

echo "I am doing next thing"
```

`output in terminal(stdout)`

```
[root@ceph examples]# sh test.sh
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
I am doing next thing
```

### What I expect?

I expect that my script print the line, "Event catch!". As you can see, my bash script ignore all while loop block and just print "I am doing next thing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal behavior of `inotifywait` is to exit after it has captured an event.

If you want `inotifywait` to keep monitoring events, you have to use the `-m` option switch.

Also in your script, you read 3 arguments from the output if `inotifywait` whereas only 2 might be returned if it has a single event. You may use the `--format` option to keep a predictable output format.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait -m -e modify ./test.txt |
while read -r filename eventlist
do
  printf 'Event catch!\nfilename=%s, eventlist=%s\n' "$filename" "$eventlist"
done

printf %s\\n "I am doing next thing"
```

If you want to exit `inotifywait`, you just kill the parent process from the pipe.

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

max_events=2
inotifywait -m -e modify ./test.txt |
while read -r filename eventlist
do
  printf 'Event catch!\nfilename=%s, eventlist=%s\n' "$filename" "$eventlist"
  max_events=$((max_events - 1))
  [ 0 -eq "$max_events" ] && kill $$
done

printf %s\\n "I am doing next thing"
```

And now with Bash arrays for events and reading a controlled format:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

max_events=2
while
  # Reads file name
  read -r -d '' filename &&
  # and reads event list in an array
  read -r -a eventlist
do
  declare -p filename eventlist
  printf 'Event catch!\nfilename! %s\neventlist: %s\n' "$filename" \
    "${eventlist[*]}"
  ((--max_events)) || break
done < <(
  inotifywait --format '%w%0%e' --monitor --event MODIFY ./test.txt
)

printf %s\\n "I am doing next thing"
```

Comment: I think you didn't recognize what I want. I already know what ```-m``` option means. It is just "monitoring forever and don't end." However, what I want is that, the commands which are between ```do``` and ```done``` work. I just tested your code in my environment But ```printf``` doesn't shown in my terminal. And also, kill command isn't triggered neither. I think there is something trouble in using ```while``` loop within inotify pipelining. But I can't figure it out so, I asked in this community.

Comment: @TyeolRik Your `while` loop is not executed because you read 3 arguments but `inotifywait` returns only 2 in your case. So the `read` returns `false` and the `while`'s inner commands are never executed.

Comment: Well, First time, your script doesn't work properly. But I figure it out what the problem is. It is how to call script ```$ sh ./test.sh``` or ```$ sudo chmod 777 ./test.sh && ./test.sh``` (I mean using sh or bash) sh doesn't work but bash does. I think I had to understand what is difference between of them lol. Anyway, thank you for your help :)